# Повторное включение файла приводит к ошибке

Tags: php

Есть основной скрипт, в котором подключаются конфигурационный файл для подключения к БД, файл с константами и файл с функцией.

```
require_once '../database/connect.php';
require_once '../conf/const.php';
require_once 'check_token.php';
```

Для выполнения функции, в свою очередь, также требуется подключение первых двух файлов.

```
function check_token($token){
    require_once '../database/connect.php';
    require_once '../conf/const.php';
```

Но выполнение основного скрипта останавливается после вызова функции `check_token`.
Каким образом нужно подключать файлы, чтобы не возникло конфликтов?

Comment: Причем тут подключение, если скрипт прекращает работу? Почему он прекращает?

Answer (score 0):

Заменил

```
function check_token($token){
    require_once '../database/connect.php';
    require_once '../conf/const.php';
```

на

```
function check_token($token){
    include '../database/connect.php';
    require_once '../conf/const.php';
```

Получается, что файлы внутри функции вообще не подключались, так как уже были подключены в основном скрипте. И из функции не были видны те переменные, которые содержатся в первом файле. При замене на `include` код из файла каждый раз просто выполняется внутри метода и всё работает.

При этом согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.php) константы доступны из любой области видимости. Поэтому для второго файла я оставил `require_once`.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php читай. И не надо будет этого геморроя с require внутри функции

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, более развёрнутый ответ, каким образом следует поступать.